# When will Biology SE become a "full' SE site?

Tags: discussion

I've checked Biology SE on the area51 site and it's been in beta phase for 1196 day as of today. I was wondering when will this site become a full site? What are the requirements?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Soon!

...ish.

The "soon" part: Biology is a strong site with great participation, great content, and a great community. As such it's been added to the list of sites we want to graduate.

The "ish" part: There are ten sites ahead of Biology in the queue, and it moves slowly because we currently wait for a custom design to be built before graduating the site. There are sites that have been in the queue since 2013 -- yeesh.

But there's hope!

[We are running an experiment on Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/425/8) to see how it goes when we graduate a site - bump up the privilege levels, hold elections, all the other fun stuff that comes with graduation - *without waiting for a unique design*. If this works, graduated sites will still get a special design -- they just won't have to wait until it's ready to graduate.

Comment: I think the unique design is nice - but not the most important thing to happen. It can also be done later.

Comment: @Chris I agree, and so do many on the team here - that's why we're testing out this pilot project. Graduation has been inextricably tied with design for many years, but many believe the time has come to divorce them.

Comment: In fact, most of the designs look fancy, but actually make it less user friendly at least in my opinion. Don't postpone important changes just for looks!! We all work in nifty labs, eat our lunches behind a desk stacked with journal articles while checking our watches in-between to see if the centrifugation is done earlier than the heat incubation. We're pragmatic Biologists here, not fashion designers. We don't care :)

Comment: Really? That's great news though a  bit surprising. We only have 5 >=10k users. I thought more were needed before a site could graduate.

Comment: @AliceD Exact description of a biologist in the lab... ;)

Comment: @terdon ChemistrySE has fewer users than BioSE, and they are graduating.