# Biology request for reopen, undeletion, etc (2015)

Tags: discussion, big-list

I decided to start this thread in light of March Ho's question [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/how-much-research-is-generally-required-for-it-to-stop-being-closed-for-homework).

---

Since many of us do not monitor post we vote close or delete, we need a way to draw attention to post that deserve another look. By drawing attention, I mean post that need to be looked at for reopening, undeletion, etc. For example, if you noticed a closed thread that has been substantial edited to fall within appropriate site guidelines, you can post it as an answer here so the others can vote to reopen.

Please do not use this thread to engage in debates on contentious matters (e.g. reasons for closure). That should be done in a separate linked thread. The goal is to keep this meta thread free of tension, so that everyone feels comfortable posting here. Please be polite, and respect the many different viewpoints in our diverse community.

To inform readers of the current (and past) states of the targeted post, please prepend tags such as:

> **Reopened, Reclosed** or
>
> **Undeleted, Redeleted**

at the start of the answer when a change of status occurs. (This also makes it easier to browse through the list by creating a visual difference for posts that still require action.)

Beware that "short" requests such as "request reopening of " may be automatically converted to comments by the SE software, so you may need to write more (e.g. why you think that the question should be reopened or undeleted).

---

The idea was borrow from math.SE [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio). Also, the linked thread will give everyone and opportunity to see how it works.

Comment: Presently, I am flagging question that should be merged as answers here. I only have 10 flags on meta so feel free to help clean up the excess meta threads with a merge request. Here is the template I am using `I started a thread to better manage this type of question. Can this be merged into an answer [here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2948/biology-request-for-reopen-undeletion-etc-2015)`

Comment: I'm not really a big fan of this kind of catch-all thread. Simple cases should be handled by the reopen queue and/or flags. More complicated cases deserve a full post with an explanation on why they should be reopened.

Comment: @MadScientist there are times when questions don't get reopened when they should even with the review queues. With such a thread, those post can be brought to light.

Comment: I also don't really see the point of this since we have the reopen queue (and undeletion cases should be very few, if any). This type of thread can be useful for retagging issues though, since the SE voting system for tags is basically impossible to use on a smallish beta site.

Comment: @fileunderwater the review queues aren't perfect since some posts still fall through the cracks. This is also used for more then reopen votes, hence, the etc. Additionally, only the first review puts a question in the queue. If someone OP or other makes a minor edit, it will in go to the queue with nothing new to offer and not get reopened. If the question is then substantially edited, it wont be in the queue, it wont be seen, and it probably wont be reopened. How do we bring that up without such a thread?

Comment: @fileunderwater If you get some users that want to dictate protocol and ban together on a deletion campaign, you will need a way to bring the post that were unjustly deleted to the attention of others. You can look to the bigger sites to see that this type of behavior does occur.

Comment: @Dustin - Great question/idea. I have the same issue with downvotes. Sometimes I go through the downvotes I placed on questions./answers and in quite some cases PO made important changes. I also often adapt an answer when being downvoted - but a great many times the downvote stays in place, despite efforts of me or PO.

Answer (score 1):

> **Reopened**

[Why do humans stop growing?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/30937/why-do-humans-stop-growing) was closed for asking personal medical advice. However, OP edited their post prior to it being closed to remove the personal aspect.

They have shown that they believe age is an attributing factor to max height so it should be reopened.

Comment: I don't understand why this Q was reopened. The edits were only cosmetic, and did not the address the problems of poor research and broad scope. Have voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

Potential duplicate. There are two questions about swimming. Question one is [Why can all animals swim in water without learning to swim but humans cannot?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7592/why-can-all-animals-swim-in-water-without-learning-to-swim-but-humans-cannot) and question two is [Can all mammals swim?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/can-all-mammals-swim) The first question is more general since it address all animals. In the answers to the first question, they mention examples of mammals that cannot swim. That is, the answer is no and it covers the other question about can mammals swim.

Should we close question two as a duplicate to question one or leave them as they are?

Comment: Yes, I think the second one is a dupe and have voted to close. One difference is however the stated scope (*animals* in the second Q, *mammals* in the first), but the answers are mostly dealing with mammals and the poster seems fine with that.

Comment: @fileunderwater I think you voted to close the first one as a dupe of the second one which is more specific. Was that your intend or do you mean the other way around as I thought it should be?

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of which one to label as duplicate. The best would be to merge them I think.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have an official response from a community mod about the status of Bio.SE. These two post

> **Closed as duplicate**

1. [What are the chances that we make it out of Beta?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/what-are-the-chances-that-we-make-it-out-of-beta?lq=1)

> **Not closed**

2. [Why are we STILL in Beta? How can we fix this?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/696/why-are-we-still-in-beta-how-can-we-fix-this?lq=1)

Should be closed as duplicates to [When will Biology SE become a "full' SE site?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2935/when-will-biology-se-become-a-full-se-site?lq=1)

There are currently 4/3 votes so we need 1/2 more vote, respectively.

Comment: I think Meta is different in this kind - we discuss things here that are important for the community. I don't think it is necessary to close these posts.

Comment: @Chris those post are outdated duplicates now that we have an official response though. Do you not agree with that?

Comment: The question is if we want to delete all "outdated" questions/answer on Meta or if we keep them to be able to understand some discussions. I don't think we should do this outside meta, though.

Comment: @Chris duplicates don't get deleted unless users vote to delete which can be done even if they are not duplicates. I am not advocating the deletion of these questions but the closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Read number 7 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Answer (score 0):

[Extreme heterozygousity in apples](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36948/what-exactly-is-extreme-heterozygosity-and-how-does-it-work)

This has been voted to close but I made substantial edits. I got some good answers but would prefer if it were left open, as I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43058/proportion-of-mass

Please can this be undeleted as I think it is now ready since edits since it was on hold. I've included the answer as a section at the end of the question as I cannot self answer questions that are deleted. It's a question about correct scientific language, the answer is "concentration" or "% by mass".

---

Also, this is very minor and I wouldn't otherwise ask, but I feel my answer here could be upvoted to 0.

[Why would a single celled organism evolve to be multi-celled?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/why-would-a-single-celled-organism-evolve-to-be-multi-celled)

Comment: So first rule in the interaction with other people online: Do not invoke emotions. Wait until you have cooled down, review the case, think about it again and then write an answer or whatever. Never do this fast and furious. This is a very old lesson...